# How to add text content first time from first API and add Images from second API in same recyclerview^

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want to show list with images and text .But problem is, data is huge when i fetch image and text in one API , it takes too much time too load. So i want to show text first from first API and show in recyclerview,which i can do. But, how to add images after that in same recyclerview, which i was calling from second API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Adapter should hold both text and image per entry.

Upon text received, you load and update the `RecyclerView` as you do, and since the image field is null, you hide or show a placeholder image.

Once the real image is ready, you update the datasource and [notifyItemChange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)), so that the cell is re-binded and you can show the image.

---

However I would strongly suggest to keep the model hold meta data (ie. `String text` and `URL image`) and use [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to handle the image loading.